# Why does the turtle not go back to its original position?

Tags: python

I tried instead of opos = turtle.pos(), opos = turtle.heading() and changed the while condition to correspond and it worked, but it doesn't work with position.

```
oPos = turtle.pos()
turtle.color(random_color())
turtle.circle(100)
turtle.setheading(turtle.heading() + 10)

while turtle.pos() != oPos:
    turtle.color(random_color())
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.setheading(turtle.heading() + 10)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what turtle are you talking about and try to provide a fully working example (including the imports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to print the values of `turtle.pos()` you will see `(-0.00, -0.00)`, so what is happening here?

Computers work with floating-point representations for numbers and some error was introduced by doing lots of sequential operations, that's why it is never a good idea to compare floats using equality.

So, with that in mind, I would suggest you to create a function to calculate the distance between two points:

```
def distance(point1, point2):
    x1, y1 = point1
    x2, y2 = point2
    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
```

And then, change your condition to test if the distance is too small, instead of exactly zero, like:

```
while distance(turtle.pos(), oPos) > 1e-10:
```

This already works, and the turtle stops as soon as it arrives at the origin position.

Answer (score 0):

The turtle is in its original position after each circle. So your while loop never enters; the original position and momentary position are always the same. See [this example](https://www.pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u10766_SCDvDi84aaNXDQjEYgBM2UPg_v1.py). In it, there is only the initial circle, because the while out condition is immediately met.

If you are trying to make many circles each offset by heading 10, then you might be looking for something like [this](https://www.pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u10766_7yJgUB9BfoLre2B5U6OCuH0s_v0.py).

```py
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
orig_heading = t.heading() - 10
while t.heading() != orig_heading:
    t.circle(100)
    t.setheading(t.heading() + 10)
```

Here you loop until your heading is back to where it was.